# Woocommerce custom user input fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-input

I have a woocommerce store setup with 2 products that come in many variants, these are wristbands.

The customer is able to customise the product by selecting the colour, size, band type and they are able to add text to the band if they want to.

I have created a variable product with various dropdowns which is all good but I have come un-stuck trying to add a text field for the user to be able to write some text that is then saved and taken through the checkout field. The file that needs to be edited is: variable.php but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I added a text field attribute to the variable product but this displays a dropdown on the front end and I don't want it to do that i need to display 2 text fields that take user input which is then saved.

I found this question: [Woocommerce Custom Product Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862740/woocommerce-custom-product-text) which is quite similar to what I want to create.

I want to do this stuff in code without having to buy an add-on and I keep coming across solutions with plugins that need to be purchased. I just need a little help with this if anyone can that would be great as I have looked online for a couple of days now and I'm sure its not difficult I just need a little help. Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really for getting free help. If you don't have proramming experience and code to share, you may want to hire someone here, or pay for a plugin.

Comment: I may not have code to share for this question but I have shared code in the past and try to do so wherever I can. I am using woocommerce for the first time and have managed to get more done than I thought with it however because I am not sure how to add these custom fields so I asked the question here. I don't think there is anything wrong with asking for someone to give me a push in the right direction after all there are people here with a lot of programming knowledge.

Comment: Honestly, just buy [this plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/), it's only $49 dollars. Although what you're asking isn't terribly *difficult*, it does require hooking the field into the front end, sanitising the data, submitting it as part of the add to cart function, passing it to the session, displaying it on the cart page, displaying it on the checkout page and then adding it to the order itself. This is not trivial, and you have to ask yourself whether the time you spend to figure all that out is worth more or less than $49.

Comment: Since it's nearly Christmas, if you really *do* want to figure this out for yourself, here's something to get you started. You'll need to hook into the following filters/actions:
 - woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button
 - woocommerce_add_cart_item_data
 - woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session
 - woocommerce_get_item_data
 - woocommerce_add_order_item_meta

Comment: Thanks @Dre for giving me a starting point I will give it a go. I have an unrelated question to ask; is it possible to over-ride the variable.php file in woocommerce. I am trying to by re-creating the file structure in my theme but it is being ignored.

Comment: *All* WooCommerce template files can be overridden simply by copying them into a `woocommerce` directory inside your theme directory and making your changes there. You need to maintain the same directory hierarchy, i.e copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` to `themes/your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`. You should do this for any changes you wish to make. **Avoid making any changes to the WooCommerce plugin files directly;** any changes you make there will be overridden next time you update the plugin.

Comment: I have copied variable.php to > themes/my-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php and made some changes but they don't show on the front end. Do I need to copy the plugins folder too? I haven't done that. Just copied from woocommerce onwards...

Comment: [Here's the WC page on overriding templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/), I'd recommend reading that. It should work; what kind of changes are you making?

Comment: I just realised my mistake my file structure looked like this: `themes/my-theme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` but I didn't need the templates folder, duh! Thanks for your help @Dre much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding this an answer so that other's might find it:

I'd strongly recommend saving yourself some time by simply purchasing the [this plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/), it's only $49 dollars. However, if you really do want to figure this out for yourself; here's something to get you started. You'll need to hook into the following filters/actions:

- woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button (to add the fields to the form)
- woocommerce_add_cart_item_data (to submit the field data)
- woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session (to add the data to the session)
- woocommerce_get_item_data (to display the data on the cart page)
- woocommerce_add_order_item_meta (to ad it to the order so it shows up in the admin area)

Comment: free: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-addon/